# Understanding Splitlines function in haskell

Tags: haskell

Below is the code segment I am trying to understand:

```
splitLines [] = []
splitLines cs =
    let (pre, suf) = break isLineTerminator cs
    in  pre : case suf of 
                ('\r':'\n':rest) -> splitLines rest
                ('\r':rest)      -> splitLines rest
                ('\n':rest)      -> splitLines rest
                _                -> []

isLineTerminator c = c == '\r' || c == '\n'
```

What I am not able to wrap my head around is what value will be allocated to "pre" in "pre :". If I am right ":" is used to append so "pre" should be prefix, but of what value ?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by "allocated"?

Comment: @melpomene I mean what value will "pre" hold in lets say first iteration of input "ab\ncd"

Comment: Well, `pre` is the first component of the return value of `break` here, so are you asking what `break` returns?

Answer (score 2):

If you would execute `break isLineTerminator "foo\r\nbar"`, then `pre` would be `"foo"` and `suf` would be `"\r\nbar"`. `break` will ensure that the second argument is split on the first occurrence where `isLineTerminator c` returns `True`, including the match that returned `True` from the passed function (`isLineTerminator` in this case) on the right-hand side.

Feeding `suf` into

```
case suf of 
    ('\r':'\n':rest) -> splitLines rest
    ('\r':rest)      -> splitLines rest
    ('\n':rest)      -> splitLines rest
    _                -> []
```

will try to remove the linebreaks from `suf`, while passing the rest (`"bar"`) to `splitLines` again. `pre` will be `"bar"` in the recursive call, while `suf` will be `""`, thus matching the last case. On the way back it will flatten `"foo" : "bar" : []` to `["foo", "bar"]` (cons operator `:`).

Comment: Excuse me, I swapped `break` with `splitLines` before. It should be fine now.

Comment: Also any reason why ('\r':'\n':rest) and not ("\r\n":rest) ?

Comment: @jayeshhathila `"\r\n" : rest` would be a type error (it would require `rest` to be a list of strings, not a list of characters). `a : b : c` parses as `a : (b : c)`.

Comment: Just to put @melpomene's comment another way: `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]`'s left operand is a _single thing_ and its right operand is a _list of things_. When you specialise `a` to `Char` you get `(:) :: Char -> String -> String`. So the expression `"\r\n" : rest` would fail to type check because in this case `(:)`'s left argument and its right argument are both `String`s, which is not valid.